# How to install NDK from SDK manager

Tags: android, android-ndk

I've seen the different questions and answers that to install NDK. they say to install NDK you should go to SDK manager, but in my SDK manager there is no any NDK:

[image]

If I must download NDK from SDK Manager then what is this?

https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/index.html

about my android Studio :

```
Android Studio 2.2

Build #AI-145.3276617, built on September 15, 2016
JRE: 1.8.0_76-release-b03 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to launch the SDK manager

There will be link at the bottom saying `Launch SDK Manager`

Click the link and you will see your SDK manager and select the items shown in the image below and install them

[image]

---

**Update :** it's clear you are using an older version which doesn't support `CMake` because this support was added to studio on `Sep 19 2016` and you build date is `Sep 15 2016` you can look at the [releases version](http://tools.android.com/download/studio/stable) and verify the release date of 2.2 android studio version at [official](http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio22andemulator2522arestable) android site under `Build` tag ,so solution is to update the studio .

You can update studio using option `Help -> Check for Update...`

Comment: @S.M_Emamian are you talking about SDK manager ? if yes then mean you have to update your android studio , are you using studio 2.2.3 ?

Comment: my android studio version is 2.2 .

Comment: @S.M_Emamian you are using the older version which has no support of `CMake`  , i have added the links to verify , the first studio version with `Cmake ` support was released on `19 Sep 2016`  , your stduio is just a close to that release but not the desired one

Comment: 2.2 supports CMake. "this support was added to studio on Sep 19 2016 and you build date is Sep 15 2016" the builds happen several days (even weeks) before release because QA takes time.